# Streamlit timeout: Your app is having trouble loading the component

Tags: streamlit

I am trying to display a Streamlit/Hydralit component but, as soon as I deploy it on Cloud Run, I encounter this timeout error (never encountered locally):

> Your app is having trouble loading the `hydralit_components.NavBar.nav_bar` component.
>
> (The app is attempting to load the component from **, and hasn't received its "streamlit:componentReady"** message.)
>
> - If this is a development build, have you started the dev server?
> - If this is a release build, have you compiled the frontend?
>
> For more troubleshooting help, please see the Streamlit Component docs or visit our forums.

[image]

How can I solve this relevant issue?

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with the aggrid component and App Engine.  I fixed by upgrading backend hardware to a F2 instance.

Comment: Is there any direct fix? Other than upgrading the hardware

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth reinstalling the component and rebooting the app. I believe this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Currently switched to Digital Ocean as provider and updated all lottie-related packages. It seems to be better now and I'm not encountering the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Streamlit [version 1.32.2](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/changelog#version-1320) is out and includes a significant improvement for custom components! The timeout warning was replaced with an element skeleton to improve the UX for slow-loading components, especially in some cloud-hosted platforms.

Comment: Thank you Jessica; on Cloud Run, the problem is unfortunately still persistent even with version 1.32.2